# VS 2013 \w web essentials ZenCoding not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials, emmet

I have installed Web Essentials with Visual Studio 2013 RC. I'm trying to use Zen Coding and nothing happens when I press tab anywhere. On top of that I want to use it from cshtml (Razor) files when writing out my html.

Is there any known issue that I could be running into here? Does Zen Coding in Web Essentials work with VS 2013 RC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably installed the RTM version of WE, which does not work on RC.
Downgrade to [0.7](http://vswebessentials.com/nightly/webessentials2013-0.7.vsix).